# Does water exist in Medieval Times, or was it not invented until the Space Age?

Tags: medieval-engineers

I have travelled a lot through the world I can see on the map, but found no rivers, lakes, oceans, not even small ponds, and no rain whatsover...

I'm not on a desert, so, where is all the water?

I can't understand how can I make bread without water, or live without drinking water, or farm without humid soil...

I've heard about a frozen/snowy area in the world, but how can snow and ice exist if water does not exist?

Comment: Thought this was History.SE for a minute, and got very confused.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff It's a joke: the developers dropped Medieval Engineers to focus on Space Engineers.

Comment: Reported on their Bugtracker: https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=396

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Considering a [mod](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/?id=1503751972) exists for adding water, I am guessing there is none in the vanilla game. Also, [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Engineers):

> set on an unnamed Earth-like planetoid **without water**

The mod itself adds quite a bit:

> - Water
> - Reworked planet
> - Sails
> - Tide system
> - Rudder
> - Rope Ladder
> - Whales
> - Anchor
> - Fishing
> - Wind vane, Ship's bell, Ship's wheel, Hollow boxes, Plank boards
> - More small stuff

The mod also links to a [water planet](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2203705951).

Comment: [Official reply](https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=396#c351): "While I'd love to have an in depth water system for ME, building something that is acceptable for vanilla is beyond the amount of work we have time for."